# Openhab (4.0.3) uses wrong network adaptor

Tags: openhab, armbian

Installed Openhab 4.0.3 on Armbian (20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)).

Openhab started and is running without errors (according to log) but `openhab-cli info`  shows, that it is running on the wrong IP address (`10.0.3.1`). It seems, it is using the network device `lxcbr0`  but it should use `br0`.

As fas as I know the `lxcbr0` device is only the bridge to the container. Openhab ist **not installed inside the container**.

I have tried to setup the correct ip address in the cfg file at `/etc/openhab/services/runtime.cfg`  with:

```
org.openhab.network:primaryAddress=192.168.178.5/24
org.openhab.network:broadcastAddress=192.168.178.5
```

and restartet the service, but this had no effect. IP still stays at: `10.0.3.1`.

Here is the result of `nmcli connection show -active`:

```
NAME               UUID   TYPE      DEVICE
br0                xxxx   bridge    br0
lxcbr0             yyyy   bridge    lxcbr0
bridge-slave-eth0  zzzze  ethernet  eth0
```

Or is this problem more related to the installed java version/configuration? (OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.8.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)).

Many thanks for any comment.